# In MATLAB, how to generate random numbers depending on the data?

Tags: matlab, random, noise

For example if `Ax = 0.0023`, it should add some noise to it and produce `newAx = 0.0027`
If `Hy = 94.54`,then `newHy = 93.42`. Initially I started using rand in MATLAB in the following manner,

```
newAx = Ax + rand
newAx = 0.9453
```

This is very much far from the parameter `Ax(0.0023)` which I have.

If I have to use range then in this case we have to use min and max of Ax. That also introduces issues like it is far from the values. As I have a system where Ax is a gradually increasing parameter at every instant of time. Now at every instant depending on the value of Ax I have to generate some random noise to get newAx which is almost close to Ax. Example if `Ax = 0.0023` generate `newAx = 0.0027` and not `newAx = 0.4590`

I need to create a random noise which depends on the data itself.

Comment: can you write down a mathematical formula that describes what you want because you haven't actually asked a question yet

Comment: @Fellman: Thanks for editing the question. It has made it more clear and made more people to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of "noise" are you trying to simulate?

rand(1)  gives you a uniform random number in the range 0 < r < 1. "[Uniform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29)" means each value is equally likely, like rolling a single, perfect die.

In other words, the random value has a range of +/- 0.5, centered around 0.5. You want to center around your actual value, and you might want to scale the range depending on the actual value. e.g.

```
 2 * (rand(1) - 0.5)
```

gives you a uniform random numbers in the range -1 < r < 1.

---

For example, if the noise should not exceed 1%, you would need to use:

```
newValue = oldValue * ( 1 +  2*(rand(1) - 0.5) * 0.01)
```

the 0.01 is the scale (1%) I used for the example, the 1 + ... centers around the original value.

---

Many processes don't have a uniform distribution. A common distribution for random noise (such as sensor noise) is a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), where values close to the center are more likely than values far from the center.

Matlab supports randn() for normal distribution.

Other distributions which model other systems can be derived from uniform random numbers.

Comment: @peterchen, Im trying out this possibility too. I am not concerned about what noise to generate, but the values should be just as close as explained in the question

Comment: to broaden my question: *why* do you need noise?

Comment: Noise is required to make the value of the parameter to get randomized around the center value to get a little difference.

Comment: @gansai: yes, but why do you need that little difference?

Comment: I am working on camera motion compensation. So at every instant of time, I need to stabilize the camera position. So I should predict new position of the camera such that it does not go far away from the initial position.

Comment: @gansai: You can use random noise to *simulate* typical camera movement, but not to *predict* it.  For a simulation, I'd use a normal distribution, though that's probably not to realistic.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use [RANDN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randn.html) to generate normally distributed noise values, then scale the standard deviation of the noise to be a percentage of the data value:

```
noiseScale = 0.05;  %# Noise with a standard deviation of %5 of the data
newAx = Ax + noiseScale*Ax*randn;
```

And if `Ax` is a *vector* of values that you want to add noise to, you can do this:

```
newAx = Ax + noiseScale.*Ax.*randn(size(Ax));
```

If you want to make sure `newAx` stays within a particular range of values, you can use the functions [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) and [MIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/min.html) like so:

```
newAx = min(newAx,maxValue);  %# Clip newAx to a maximum of maxValue
newAx = max(newAx,minValue);  %# Clip newAx to a minimum of minValue
```

Comment: @peterchen: I'm pretty sure RANDN generates positive *and* negative values. I'll check on it.

Comment: @peterchen: I just checked it. RANDN *does* generate both positive and negative values, so the above code will create larger *and* smaller values for `newAx`.

Comment: You are right, I mixed up rand&randn, sorry for the confusion - removed incorrect comment.

Comment: and @peterchen: Thanks for the support. I'm working on it and will let you know as soon as possible once it creates the set of parameters which come to be nearly to the original values.

Answer (score 2):

```
newDatum = oldDatum+2*(rand(1)-0.5)*oldDatum
```

Comment: simpler is this equivalent: newDatum = 2*rand(1)*oldDatum

Comment: @David: That would not center the values around oldDatum

Comment: @peterchen my code is just a rearrangement of that posted in the answer by @High Performance Mark

Comment: @David, oh, right when using the factor 2, that works out. However, in most applicaitons thsi one neds to be adjusted. (Wasn't my best day yesterda,y obviously)

Comment: @High Performance Mark:This code does not seem to get to the values as near as possible.

Comment: @gansai: this code is a poor example and not intended for production use.  I merely offer it as a suggestion for how you could make the errors you add to your data depend on the data itself.  I leave the hard work up to you, and I see that other SOers have also made suggestions.